# Get variable type (ADO Object or String) in ASP Classic?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to write a function in ASP Classic that accepts a parameter; but the parameter can either be a String, or an ADODB.Command Object.  How can the function determine which type the parameter is?

So...

```
Function myfunction( input )
    If is_ADODBCommand( input ) Then
        ' do stuff to object'
    ElseIf is_string( input ) Then
        ' do stuff to string'
    End If
End Function
```

Basically, please tell me how to do `is_ADODBCommand` and `is_string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [VarType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kfz157h(v=vs.84).aspx) for primitive types.

```vb
is_string = (VarType(input) = vbString)
```

For object types, you can use [TypeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y58s1cs6(v=vs.84).aspx) since VarType returns a generic type specifier `vbObject` which gives no clue about the object's kind.

```vb
is_ADODBCommand = (TypeName(input) = "Command")
```